# i need to replace digits in list alphabet starting from index key_m in alphabet of digits in list m_b by index in list c1

Tags: python, list, replace

I need to replace digits in list alphabet starting from index key_m in alphabet of digits in list m_b by index in list c1

```
from operator import setitem

def replace():

alphabet = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'],
        ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['j'], ['k'], ['l'],
        ['m'], ['n'], ['o'], ['p'], ['q'], ['r'],
        ['s'], ['t'], ['u'], ['w'], ['v'], ['x'],
        ['y'], ['z']]

key_m = 10
c1 = [17, 10, 21, 22, 1]

m_b = [['y'], ['a'], ['#'], ['b'], ['o'], ['i'],
       ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'],
       ['j'], ['k'], ['l'], ['m'], ['n'], ['p'],
       ['q'], ['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u'], ['v'],
       ['w'], ['x'], ['z'], ['_'], ['-'], ['!'],
       ['?'], ['$'], ['/'], ["@"], ['+'], ['%']]

for b, c in zip(c1, m_b):
    setitem(alphabet, b, c)

print(alphabet)
```

**expected result is alphabet = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['j'], ['p'], ['g'],['t'], ['u'], ['a'], ['p'], ['q'], ['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u'], ['w'], ['v'], ['x'],['y'], ['z']]**

**but the actual result is alphabet = [['a'], ['o'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['j'], ['a'], ['l'], ['m'], ['n'], ['o'], ['p'], ['q'], ['y'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u'], ['#'], ['b'], ['x'], ['y'], ['z']]**

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: ... and the actual result? And the specific problem with which you're stuck? Welcome to SO. Please make sure to read [ask]

Comment: expected result is alphabet = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['j'], ['p'], ['g'],['t'], ['u'], ['a'], ['p'], ['q'], ['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u'], ['w'], ['v'], ['x'],['y'], ['z']]

Comment: [edit] your post to add the expected output ?

Comment: why a list of list and not just a long string ?

Comment: sorry i need it to look and work like a matrix

Comment: Please clarify, that is very unclear what should replace what

Comment: Why does 5 letters change in the middle ?

Comment: what is `m_b` for ? It seems useless

Comment: i need to replace the index key_m wich is = 10 and the next numbers which is = 11, 12 , 13 ,14  in alphabet with c1 indixes in m_b wich is [17, 10, 21, 22, 1]

Comment: m_b for getting the new characters from to shuffle alphabet

Comment: finally getting it

Comment: i am making an algorithm for encrypting if you want to see the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to iterate on `c1` values, wrap in `enumerate` to have indices increasing (starting at `key_m`) then set the values

```
key_m = 10
c1 = [17, 10, 21, 22, 1]
for idx, value in enumerate(c1, start=key_m):
    alphabet[idx] = m_b[value]
```

---

I maintain that using 1d list and string would be nicer

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']

m_b = 'ya#boicdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxz_-!?$/@+%'

key_m = 10
c1 = [17, 10, 21, 22, 1]
for idx, value in enumerate(c1, start=key_m):
    alphabet[idx] = m_b[value]

print(alphabet)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'p', 'g', 't',
# 'u', 'a', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: @IxDante you may want to take one minute, to ensure that this 2d list is mandatory, lists of 1 values are in most cases a bad idea, sess my edit

Comment: yooo how can i contact you i want to show you my code and algorithm if you can ?

Comment: @IxDante https://pastebin.com/ use that, but I'll just take a few minute to look at it, no more ;)

Comment: sorry got it fixed it thanks, but i just got 2 small problems to solve and my project is done can you help me ?

Comment: if the key_m = 24 how to make the code return to the index [0]

Comment: cant it be done ? @azro

Comment: @IxDante use modulo : `value % len(m_b)`

Comment: azro thank u all my problem got solved except one can you help me with it ? @azro

Comment: @IxDante tell me I'll see